# iOS Swift - segue to a class - passing Int value from a ViewController to a Class using prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to push value of variable cellNumber located in ViewOne (ViewController) to variable trackNumber located at RadioPlayer (class RadioPlayer) buy using below code in ViewOne:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    //var DestViewControler : ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
    var Dest2ViewControler : RadioPlayer = segue.destinationViewController as! RadioPlayer

   // DestViewControler.trackNumber = cellNumber
    Dest2ViewControler.trackNumber = cellNumber
}
```

but I am getting bellow error when running the app:

```
 Could not cast value of type 'The_Radio_App.ViewController' (0x73e48) to 'The_Radio_App.RadioPlayer' (0x745a8).
```

and this line of code is highlighted in green:
    var Dest2ViewControler : RadioPlayer = segue.destinationViewController as! RadioPlayer

So I think what is causing a problem here is this: segue.destinationViewController - because RadioPlayer is not a ViewController but just a class. How can I amend this to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates the `segue.destinationViewController` is an object of type `ViewController` not of type `RadioPlayer`. As a result, your forced cast is causing a crash, because you are making an incorrect assertion to the compiler.

In your storyboard, go to scene representing the destination of this segue. Go the identity inspector for the view controllor of that scene. (Select the yellow box in the storyboard to select the VC, and then check the 2nd or 3rd item in the right panel.) Make sure that the field defining the class says "RadioPlayer".

Comment: Hi Thank you for this, but I am not using RadioPlayer as ViewController for any of the story boards - its just a class that I am using for holding functions for playing sounds. Can I use segue only to transfer values between ViewControllers? Can it not be used for transferring values from ViewController to a class?

Comment: No. Segues are only for managing transitions and embedding relationships between view controllers. If you are not transitioning to a new view controller, then make the RadioPlayer object a property of your current view controller class. Instead of triggering a segue, call a method on an IBAction method which you define on that view controller. In that method, update the trackNumber of the radio player object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let dest2ViewControler = segue.destinationViewController as! Dest2ViewController

destViewControler.radioPlayer.trackNumber = cellNumber
```

Where `radioPlayer` is the RadioPlayer member variable in your `Dest2ViewController` class